# user defined base class in python

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, abstract-class, derived-class

I was working with a python library, then I noticed a specific base class has been defined and all other classes derivative from it. 
my question is why we need such definition and structure in coding a library

```
class baseclass(object):
 def __init__(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("this is an abstract class")

 def __enter__(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("this is an abstract class")

 def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    raise NotImplementedError("this is an abstract class")

class Myclass(baseclass):
  def __init__(self):
    ""

 def __enter__(self):
   ""

 def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    ""
 def method1(self):
   pass
```

Comment: It really depends on the situation. There is not nearly enough information here to answer, and too many possible hypotheticals.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes are usually parent classes, you can think a parent class that has class variables that the child class will inherit from the Parent. Abstract classes are dependent on situation as mentioned in @Mad Physicist answer. you can consider using abstract classes if any of these statements apply to your situation:

You want to share code among several closely related classes.
You expect that classes that extend your abstract class have many common methods or fields or require access modifiers other than public (such as protected and private).
You want to declare non-static or non-final fields. This enables you to define methods that can access and modify the state of the object to which they belong.

Comment: Your quote really isn't about python, and sounds like it is referring to Java/C++ or a similar language.

Comment: As I understood, the question is "why we need such definition and structure in coding a library". I am just trying to explain it why we need this structure. But, you are also right my answer become very general in nature.